# Web API2 read request body

Tags: vb.net

I have a web API2 item that I need to read the 'body' of the incoming request. The client is sending information (via 'PUT') in the body opposed to parameters in the URL. I have been searching for a solution but keep hitting a wall. Can anyone advise how I can get this body text?

Thanks

```
<HttpOptions>
<Route("v1/cth/test"), AcceptVerbs("PUT", "POST", "OPTIONS")>
Public Function CTHInterface(ByVal passedjson As Object) As String
    Return "Hello"
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI, I finally managed to get to the body. Hope this helps someone else.

```
    <HttpOptions>
   <Route("v1/cth/dev"), AcceptVerbs("PUT", "POST", "OPTIONS")>
    Public Function CTHInterfaceDev() As String
        Dim CTHStream As New StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream)
        Dim CTHBody As String = CTHStream.ReadToEnd
        Return "Hello"
    End Function
```